# function returning 1 instead of actual value

Tags: php, mysql

```
$userfetch = "select usr_cns_id from user_canvas where email_id='".$dat['loginID']."' "; 
function cnct($sname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$databasename)
{
    mysql_connect($sname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$databasename) or die("COULD NOT CONNECT");
    mysql_select_db($databasename) or die("COULD NOT SELECT DB");
    global $userfetch;
    //echo $sname."".$dbusername."".$dbusername."".$databasename;
    $userfetch_exec = mysql_query($userfetch);

    //$userdetails = array();
    while($udata = mysql_fetch_assoc($userfetch_exec))
    {
        $userdetails = $udata ;
    }

    foreach($userdetails as $ude)
    {
        $udetail = $ude['usr_cns_id'];  
    }

    return $udetail;
}
```

/*First time i am calling this function and it works fine */

```
  $uscanid = cnct($server_name,$Db_user,$Db_pass,$Db_name_ac);
```

/*Second time i call this function with different parameter values and it returns 1 instead of actual value */

```
 $uscanid = cnct($server_name,$Db_user,$Db_pass,$Db_name_comp);
```

/*I cant understand where am going wrong , any help is appreciated */

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Docs..](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect)

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments,
> no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
> the already opened link will be returned.

So you need to set the `$newlink` parameter to TRUE on your `mysql_connect()`

Like this.. (*Change your existing code to this*)

```
mysql_connect($sname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,TRUE);
```

---

**Warning** : This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: I set the new link to true , but still its returning 1 only and not real value.

Comment: Please see this example from PHP Manual. http://in3.php.net/function.mysql-connect#82040

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass $userfetch to function

```
function cnct($sname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$databasename, $userfetch)
```